# InvalidOperationException for MVC website but not WCF services

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, wcf

I have 3 projects:

1. WCF Services (Services)
2. MVC 5 Website (Website)
3. Class Library (Library)

I've installed Entity Framework v6.0.0.0 on all projects.
In my library I've enabled code migrations and added the domain models, DTOs, a couple of view models and a data access layer, one query/DAL looks like so:

```
public class WebsiteLayer {
    EntitiesContext db;

    public WebsiteLayer()
        : this(new EntitiesContext()) { }
    public WebsiteLayer(EntitiesContext _db) {
        db = _db;
    }

    public List<ItemViewModel> GetStuff() { 
        return (from i in db.Items.Include(x => x.Inventory)
                     select new ItemViewModel() {
                         ID = i.ID,
                         Name = i.Name,
                         Qty = i.Inventory.Sum(x => x.Qty)
                     }).ToList();

    }

}
```

So I use the same line of code in both my Services and Website projects:

```
        WebsiteLayer dal = new WebsiteLayer();
        var test = dal.GetStuff();
```

When this code is run in the Services everything works fine and I get my list of projected viewmodels back from the method. Top job.

When I run this code on my Website it flops and tells me the backing model has changed with an `InvalidOperationException`. What the hell?

So to summarise the *shared library* works for the WCF services project but not the MVC website project.

All projects have the same version of EF installed, the connection string exists in each of the relevant config files.

I did initially create the database using the Services but I've since deleted the DB and migrations and ran `add-migration InitialCreate` and `update-database` from the website. The website project has been able to successfully create a DB in the right location and the Services can successfully get information from there, but the website still states that the backing model has changed.

What could this be?

**Edit 1:**
I've ran a clean `Update-Database -verbose` command in the package manager console each time deleting the database and both outputs are the same:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Inventories] (
[ID] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
[Qty] [int] NOT NULL,
[LocationID] [int] NOT NULL,
[ItemID] [int] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Inventories] PRIMARY KEY ([ID])
)
CREATE INDEX [IX_LocationID] ON [dbo].[Inventories]([LocationID])
CREATE INDEX [IX_ItemID] ON [dbo].[Inventories]([ItemID])
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Items] (
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [Code] [nvarchar](max),
    [RefCode] [nvarchar](max),
    [Name] [nvarchar](max),
    [CreatedOn] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [UOM] [nvarchar](max),
    [UnitOfMeasureID] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Items] PRIMARY KEY ([ID])
)
CREATE INDEX [IX_UnitOfMeasureID] ON [dbo].[Items]([UnitOfMeasureID])
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UnitOfMeasures] (
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [Name] [nvarchar](max),
    [SortOrder] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.UnitOfMeasures] PRIMARY KEY ([ID])
)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Locations] (
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [Name] [nvarchar](max),
    [Code] [nvarchar](max),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Locations] PRIMARY KEY ([ID])
)
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Inventories] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Inventories_dbo.Items_ItemID] FOREIGN KEY ([ItemID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Items] ([ID]) ON DELETE CASCADE
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Inventories] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Inventories_dbo.Locations_LocationID] FOREIGN KEY ([LocationID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Locations] ([ID]) ON DELETE CASCADE
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Items] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Items_dbo.UnitOfMeasures_UnitOfMeasureID] FOREIGN KEY ([UnitOfMeasureID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[UnitOfMeasures] ([ID]) ON DELETE CASCADE
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[__MigrationHistory] (
    [MigrationId] [nvarchar](150) NOT NULL,
    [ContextKey] [nvarchar](300) NOT NULL,
    [Model] [varbinary](max) NOT NULL,
    [ProductVersion] [nvarchar](32) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.__MigrationHistory] PRIMARY KEY ([MigrationId], [ContextKey])
)
INSERT [dbo].[__MigrationHistory]([MigrationId], [ContextKey], [Model], [ProductVersion])
VALUES (N'201406021411556_InitialCreate', N'InventoryLibrary.Migrations.Configuration',  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
```

Comment: There's something subtle happening to your database. I'm not sure what it is, but you can detect it by creating the db with your website, script the db to a file, delete the db (and migrations), create the db with the service, script the db again to a separate file, and then compare the two db scripts.

Comment: Also, are your relevant portions of the `web.config` identical?

Comment: Yes the config files are the same.

Comment: When I use the Package Manager Console, I select the default project to "Library" on the Website and Services projects so although I find it hard to believe, I'm willing to try anything right about now, I'll post back with results

Comment: @ChristopherStevenson I've added the verbose output for the script both are exactly the same.

Comment: are the references all correct? are the website and service referencing the library and thay have no reference to each other? and most importantly is the library referencing other things which are in turn referenced by either of the two presentation layers?

Comment: @Tallmaris References are all correct, one way to the library. I do have Automapper, Devexpress and a couple other nuget packages?

Comment: My suspicion is that have two applications with migrations enabled is an issue. I think one will have to be the 'master' and the other throw an exception if the DB doesn't match the model.

Comment: After further investigation I've found this is something to do with the new authentication/userprofiles in MVC 5. The same setup works with a MVC 4 website.